# How to get all the values from a xml, using JAXB and Spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jaxb

guys. I'm making a web application with Spring MVC and JAXB. I need to get all the content of the row tags from a xml file which contains 45 000 rows and put them into a table in the browser. This is how the rows look like.

```
<row>  0  0  0 HE++  0       36086.8       36116.5             0          0.52          0.86</row>
<row>  0  0  1 O+  0       36086.8       36116.5             0          0.38          0.62</row>
<row>  0  0  2 H+  0       36086.8       36116.5             0             0             0</row>
```

My Controller class is

```
@Controller
```

public class ControllerRows {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rows", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRows(){

    try{

        File file = new File("D:/JavaProjects/ProjectClient/Canon.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Canon.class);      
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Canon canon = (Canon) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        List<Table> table = canon.getTable();

        for(Table tables: table){

            List<String> row = tables.getRow();

                    String items;

                            String value1 = null;
                            String value2 = null;
                            String value3 = null;
                            String value4 = null;
                            String value5 = null;
                            String value6 = null;
                            String value7 = null;
                            String value8 = null;
                            String value9 = null;
                            String value10 = null;

                            for(int i=0;i<row.size();){

                                items = row.get(i++);

                                String[] parts = items.split(" +");

                                String part1 = parts[1];
                                String part2 = parts[2];
                                String part3 = parts[3];
                                String part4 = parts[4];
                                String part5 = parts[5];
                                String part6 = parts[6];
                                String part7 = parts[7];
                                String part8 = parts[8];
                                String part9 = parts[9];
                                String part10 = parts[10];

                                value1 = parts[1];
                                value2 = parts[2];
                                value3 = parts[3];
                                value4 = parts[4];
                                value5 = parts[5];
                                value6 = parts[6];
                                value7 = parts[7];
                                value8 = parts[8];
                                value9 = parts[9];
                                value10 = parts[10];

                            }
                            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Rows");              

                            model.addObject("part1", value1);
                            model.addObject("part2", value2);
                            model.addObject("part3", value3);
                            model.addObject("part4", value4);
                            model.addObject("part5", value5);
                            model.addObject("part6", value6);
                            model.addObject("part7", value7);
                            model.addObject("part8", value8);
                            model.addObject("part9", value9);
                            model.addObject("part10", value10);

                            return model;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

and this is my jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center><h1>Table</h1></center>
<table border=1> 
<tr>
<td>${part1}</td>
<td>${part3}</td>
<td>${part4}</td>
<td>${part5}</td>
<td>${part6}</td>
<td>${part7}</td>
<td>${part8}</td>
<td>${part9}</td>
<td>${part10}</td> 
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So far i splitted the rows by spaces to put them in different cells, but when i start the browser, i get only the last row of the xml. When i start it with system.out.println, i get all of them in the console. Can someone help me with this? How to get all of them in the browser into my table?

Comment: That is exactly what you are doing, you are only storing the last row. However I would say it is a bad idea to load all the rows in memory, parse them and store them again in memory, you likely will run into issues with memory and performance. I would say you are probably better of using an [`XsltView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/xslt/XsltView.html). Create an XSL and let that convert the XML to HTML. Is more memory efficient and saves you from munging yourself (although you have to learn XSL now).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but what is the way to store all of them, not only the last one?